# Displaying dataview information

Tags: c#, datagridview, radio-button

How do I sort what information is being assigned to the data view using `RadioButtons`?

```
private void btnSearchByGender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView data = new DataView(pID2dbDataSet.customer);

    data.RowFilter = "Gender=" + rdoMale.Select();
    customerDataGridView.DataSource = data;
}
```

So far I've got this but I'm not sure how to select what radio button does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void btnSearchByGender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView data = new DataView(pID2dbDataSet.customer);

    string gender;
    if (rdoMale.Checked)
        gender = "Male"
    else
       gender = "Female"
    data.RowFilter = "Gender = '" + gender + "'";
    customerDataGridView.DataSource = data;
}
```